# QML XmlListModel: Query nodes with attributes

Tags: xml, qt, qml

I'm trying to make a small RSS application with QML and want to query the [Tagesschau atom feed](http://www.tagesschau.de/xml/atom/). It basically looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/resources/xsl/atom_xsl.jsp" type="text/xsl"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <entry>
        <title>Lufthansa setzt Flüge nach Kairo aus</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>Telefonat zwischen Hunt und Sarif: Das Misstrauen bleibt</title>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

The corresponding QML XmlListModel I have defined is this:

```
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

Item {
    XmlListModel {
        id: xmlfeed
        source: "http://www.tagesschau.de/xml/atom/"

        query: "/feed/entry"

        XmlRole { name: "title"; query: "title/string()" }
    }

    Component {
        id: feeditem

        Label {
            text: title
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: feedlist
        model: xmlfeed
        clip: true

        anchors { fill: parent; margins: 2 }

        delegate: feeditem
    }
}
```

However, this does not work. QML does not find any list items. I found out that the crucial part is the line:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

If I manually download the file and edit this line into just

```
<feed>
```

QML can parse it. Do you know, how to fix this? Do I need to improve my `query` string or is this a bug in QML?

Answer (score 1):

XPath itself doesn't have a way to bind a namespace prefix with a namespace. You can declare the namespace using [XmlListModel.namespaceDeclarations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html#namespaceDeclarations-prop). In your case that should look like the code in the example from the link above:

```
XmlListModel {
        id: xmlfeed
        source: "http://www.tagesschau.de/xml/atom/"
        namespaceDeclarations: "declare default element namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom';"
        query: "/feed/entry"
        XmlRole { name: "title"; query: "title/string()" }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this solves the problem. However, my initial goal was to say XmlListModel to just ignore all attributes, so for example `<feed foobar=bla>` will be recognized, too. Do you know, if this is possible?